# Brute force solution without itertools in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, brute-force

I'm new to Python. 
I'm trying to calculate `3 ** 16 (¹[0-f], ²[0-f], ³[0-f])`
but it's not working properly.
This is my code:

```
inp = str(input('value len 0-3 digit:'))
hexa = ('0123456789abcdef');
#len(hexa) = 16 digit
#pass = '36f'
pass = inp
for x in range(0, 3 ** len(hexa)):
#range = 0..(3 ^ 16)
    if(hexa[x] == pass):
        found = hexa[x]
#if result valid
        print("pos: %d, pass: %s" % (x, found))
#print position
```

I got the error "index out of bound".
I need output like this:

```
000 #first
001
002
...
...
36f #found then break
...
...
fff #last
```

How do I fix it?

Comment: Do not name your variable `pass` because that is a built-in keyword.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your `IndexError: string index out of range` error comes from this logic:

```
for x in range(0, 3 ** len(hexa)):
```

Which probably should be:

```
for x in range(len(hexa) ** len(inp)):
```

A much smaller number.  This is never going to work on input of more than one digit:

```
if(hexa[x] == pass):
```

You need to rethink this.  Using Python's own `hex()` function, I came up with an approximation of what I'm guessing you're trying to do:

```
hexadecimal = input('hex value of 1-3 digits: ').lower()

hex_digits = '0123456789abcdef'

for x in range(len(hex_digits) ** len(hexadecimal)):
    if hex(x) == "0x" + hexadecimal:
        print("pos: %d, pass: %s" % (x, hexadecimal))
        break
```

**OUTPUT**

```
> python3 test.py
hex value of 1-3 digits: 36f
pos: 879, pass: 36f
>
```

If that's not what you're trying to do, please explain further in your question.

Other issues to consider: don't use `pass` as the name of a variable, it's a Python keyword; `input()` returns a `str`, you don't need to call `str` on it; avoid semicolons (;) in Python.